# action method not working on input in playframework2.0

Tags: playframework-2.2

I have created a web application which should take input from website and display it on a new page. I notice that my code is not getting called at all.

Routes file - I call localhost:9000 first. test method in Data controller is called which displays an input box and a submit button. Problem is on clicking submit, nothing happens

```
GET     /data                       controllers.Data.test
GET     /data/post                  controllers.Data.post
```

Model - what I enter in input should get mapped to User object using a form and get displayed in new page

```
case class User (name:String)
```

Controller code

```
object Data extends Controller {
val userForm = Form((mapping("name"->text))(User.apply)(User.unapply))

//this gets called for url localhost:9000/data



def test = Action {
Ok(views.html.dataIndex(None))


}

//PROBLEM - this should get called on clicking submit button but it doesn't get called



 def post = Action { implicit request =>
    println("in post")
    val u:User = userForm.bindFromRequest().get
Ok(views.html.dataIndex(Some(u)))


 }
}
```

View

```
@(u:Option[User])

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @u match {
        case Some(user) => {
        <h1> You entered </h1>
      <ul id="hardcode-list" >
        <li>@user.name</li>
        </ul>
        }
        case None => {
        <h1>Feed User Data</h1>
        <form action="/data/post" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="button" name="send" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        }
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake. The button type should be 'submit'